# Why is this a retain cycle?

Tags: ios, swift, automatic-ref-counting

I have basic understanding of ARC but in the following example I suddenly get really confused.

`FeedViewController` has a strong reference of `NetworkHelper`, then the `NetworkHelper` has a function which takes a closure and call it later.

So here's the confusion: 
the closure is passed from `FeedViewController` to `NetworkHelper`, And this block is not being retained inside `NetworkHelper`, so why does `NetworkHelper` has a strong reference of `NetworkHelper`? this is stated in an article but I just could't figure out why. It makes sense to me only if `NetworkHelper` keep a strong reference to the block.

```
class NetworkHelper {
    func getFeed(completion: @escaping ([FeedItem]) -> Void) {
        Alamofire.request(…).responseJSON { (response) in
            if let value = response.result.value {
                if let json = JSON(value)[Constants.items].array {
                    completion(json.flatMap(FeedItem.init))
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class FeedViewController {
    var tableView: UITableViewController
    var feedItems: [FeedItem]
    var networkHelper: NetworkHelper
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        ...
        networkHelper.getFeed() { items in
            self.feedItems = items
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "*this is stated in an article"* - what article? Is this your code or did you copy it from the article without proper attribution?

Comment: the network helper block creates a strong reference to self inside FeedViewController. You have to use: `networkHelper.getFeed() {[weak self] items in
            self?.feedItems = items
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, there is no cycle.

First of all, `NetworkHelper` never owns anything, it just passes a closure to `Alamofire`.

`Alamofire` holds to that closure, which retains a `FeedViewController` instance (as `self`). However, `Alamofire` is not owned by `FeedViewController`, therefore there is no cycle.

It's true that while the request is running, `FeedViewController` cannot be deallocated because the completion callback prevents that, but that could be an expected behavior and there is definitely no ownership cycle.